# Amazon ec2 centos 6 spot instance root volume

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos6

The issue I have is that the root volume on centos AMIs seems to be set to 8GB regardless of what it says in the management console.

There are many posts online regarding re-partitioning and rebooting, though the instances need to be provisioned with Ansible and be available as spot instances.

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvde    202:64   0  40G  0 disk 
└─xvde1 202:65   0   8G  0 part /
```

Is there a way to reconfigure without rebooting or starting the instance with the correct partition?

```
[root@ip-172-XX-XX-70 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1      7.9G  797M  6.7G  11% /
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm


[root@ip-172-XX-XX-70 ~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)  
The filesystem is already 2096896 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Linux partition expert but there are a couple of possible workarounds I would use.

1) create a custom ami, to do this launch an instance in the normal way, correct the partition size, take a snapshot. You can then use this AMI instead of the CentOS one you're currently using (also helpful if you want to do things like pre install programs) it does mean you'd still be stuck with a static partition size, depends on your use case if that's an issue.

2) use an official AMI, I dont have the full list, or what exactly it is that makes them different but you'll find certain official AMIs, amazon Linux, rhel, windows off the top of my head automatically start with the corrected disk size, if you can move to amazon Linux for example which I believe is a very close fork of centos (at a guess), problem solved.

Good Luck

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. Its already a custom AMI and should have the correct partition size. It's just when starting new instances it seems to default to 8Gb root on centos. I have tried a couple of official centos AMIs and have the same problem. I'll double check our one and try resize and snapshot. It needs to be centos as closest to production. Ideally would be redhat. That doesn't have this problem but doesn't support spot instances.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure that "official" is the correct term, the only distinguishing feature other than correct partition sizing I've noticed is that when you go to launch a completely new instance you will be shown a tab that contains aws Linux, red hat and windows each one of these should recognise partition size correctly. If you click to the community or marketplace tabs these are "unofficial". For example the main rhel 6 pv image provided by amazon does not have a problem, neither does the rhel 7 hvm.

Comment: However we met the same issue you are seeing when we tried to switch to rhel 6 hmv which appears to be an one of those unofficial ones I was talking about. Sorry I don't have more detail we never bothered to investigate much further.

Comment: I have just come across this whilst searching for another issue - it may be of use, there is no mention of restarting at least - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146271/increase-the-root-device-size-in-cloudformation-autoscaling-group

Comment: Hi thanks for the link. I tried resize2fs and it didnt seem to work but I'll give it another go. Thanks